# Calculus Derivative I have the work for the problem I'm just not sure where one part comes from

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm new to this so I don't know how the formatting works sorry.

So I have all the work for it there is just one thing I don't understand where it is coming from.... I know its a double chain rule too.

$y=ln\sqrt\frac{(x^2-8)}{(x^2+8)}$

take derivative

$=\sqrt\frac{(x^2+8)}{(x^2-8)}\cdot1/2\cdot\frac{((x^2-8)}{(x^2+8))^-1/2}\cdot\frac{(2x(x^2+8)-2x(x^2-8))}{(x^2+8)^2}$

$=\frac{(x^2+8)}{(x^2-8)}\cdot\frac{(16x)}{(x^2+8)^2}$

$=\frac{16x}{(x^4-64)}$

The part I don't understand is where did the 1/2 come from??

Comment: You may consult the on-site [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for help on proper formatting.

Comment: I think that half comes from finding the derivative of inner function.The one enclosed within ln()

Answer (score 1):

We have, by chain rule,

> $$\dfrac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(x)}}\cdot f^\prime(x)$$

---

Just for the record, there's an easier way:

$$y=\ln\sqrt{\frac{x^2-8}{x^2+8}}=\ln\left(\frac{x^2-8}{x^2+8}\right)^{{1/2}}={\frac{1}{2}}\ln\left(\frac{x^2-8}{x^2+8}\right)\\ \implies y=\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln(x^2-8)-\ln(x^2+8)\right)$$

Now, apply chain rule.

Comment: $$\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)=\frac{\rm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(f(x)\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)\right)^{-1/2}\cdot f^\prime(x)$$

Comment: So I tried doing it the easier way mentioned above but I'm not getting the correct answer. Instead of 16x/(x^4-64)   I am getting 2x^2/(x^4-64)

Comment: @Molly, I'm not able to spot your mistake, but I'm giving the rest of the solution here:

$$y^\prime=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2-8}-\frac{2x}{x^2+8}\right)=\frac{2x}{~2}\cdot \frac{x^2+8-x^2+8}{(x^2+8)(x^2-8)}=\frac{16x}{x^4-64}$$
  
Make sure you used the chain rule correctly.

Comment: @Molly, I think you forgot to use the chain rule to differentiate the $x^2$ part inside the $\ln(x^2\pm 8)$

Comment: You're right! That's what I forgot. Sorry to ask so many questions. but I understand you factor out a 2x but how does it become x^2+8x-x^2+8

Comment: @Molly, do you know that $\dfrac{1}{a}\pm \dfrac{1}{b}=\dfrac{b\pm a}{ab}$ ?

Comment: I would rather have $e^{2y} = 1+\frac{16}{x^2-8}$ then apply implicit differentiation.

Comment: @GohP.iHan, yeah, that works too.